# AArch64 - calling sprintf from EL2 and EL1

Tags: arm, arm64

I have written a simple arm64 bare-metal program to switch between EL2 and EL1. In EL2 and EL1, I am calling sprintf function as shown below.

```
void EL2Handler()
{
   char buffer[100];
   sprintf(buffer, "Current Exception Level is 2");
   ...
}

void EL1Handler()
{
   char buffer[100];
   sprintf(buffer, "Current Exception Level is 1");
   ...
}
```

When the sprintf called from EL1, it throws a synchronous exception. What could be the reason? Could it be related to memory access permissions? I am emulating this code on QEMU using virt machine.

The code is compile using

```
aarch64-none-elf-gcc -I.   -nostartfiles -ffreestanding --specs=rdimon.specs -L. -Wl,-T,qemu-virt-aarch64.ld -o test.elf startup.s test.c
```

The execute line is

```
qemu-system-aarch64 -semihosting -m 1024M -nographic  -machine virt,gic-version=2,virtualization=on -cpu max -kernel test.elf -S -gdb tcp::9000
```

This instruction causes the exception,

```
 0x400012cc <sprintf+60> ldp q16, q17, [x1]. 
 (gdb) p /x $x1 $2 = 0x47effdf8  
 (gdb) p /x $sp $3 = 0x47effdc0  
 (gdb) p /x $ESR_EL1 $5 = 0x1fe00000
```

The exception class in ESR_EL1 is `0b000111` *"Access to SVE, Advanced SIMD or floating-point functionality trapped by CPACR_EL1.FPEN, CPTR_EL2.FPEN, CPTR_EL2.TFP, or CPTR_EL3.TFP control......"*. Is there a chance for floating point/sve/simd not implemented in EL1?

Comment: Look at `ESR_ELn` for whatever exception level the exception is taken to.

Comment: This instruction causes the exception `0x400012cc <sprintf+60> ldp q16, q17, [x1]`.  `(gdb) p /x $x1
$2 = 0x47effdf8

(gdb) p /x $sp
$3 = 0x47effdc0

(gdb) p /x $ESR_EL1
$5 = 0x1fe00000` The exception class in ESR_EL1 is `0b000111` "Access to SVE, Advanced SIMD or floating-point functionality trapped by CPACR_EL1.FPEN, CPTR_EL2.FPEN, CPTR_EL2.TFP, or CPTR_EL3.TFP control......".  Is there a chance for floating point/sve/simd not implemented in EL1?

Comment: For ARM32 TrustZone, the registers are *NOT* banked between worlds.  The handler must save registers, including fp/simd registers.  I would guess it is the same for ARM64 and hypervisor levels.  An exception level may not use fp/simd and so they do not need to be save/restored.  There are also other bit flags that can restrict a level/world from using fp/simd and throw an exception if they do.  I think the quoted *CPACR_EL1.FPEN* is a good hint.

Comment: @LittleTree What are the values of `CPACR_EL1`, `CPTR_EL2` and `HCR_EL2`?